# matplotlib subplots not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, plot, rows

The right column plots aren't showing up, any idea what's going on?? I can stack them on top of each other but when I try to make two columns, the right column doesn't show up. also, when I try %matplotlib notebook, the figure disappears altogether. I've included a screen shot of what my figure looks like.

```
%matplotlib inline

# RING 1 PLOTS

fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

axs[0,0].plot(t, ring.IN_1.soma_v, color='black', label='IN soma')
axs[0,0].plot(t, ring.IN_1.dend_prox_v, color='grey', label='IN prox dend')
axs[0,0].plot(t, ring.IN_1.dend_dist_v, color='red', label='IN dist dend')
axs[0,0].plot(t, ring.IN_1.dend_dist2_v, color='blue', label='IN dist2 dend')
axs[0,0].legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False)
axs[0,0].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[0,0].set_xticks([])
axs[0,0].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[0,0].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[1,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[0].soma_v, color='black', label='TC1 soma')
axs[1,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[0].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC1 dend')
axs[1,0].legend(frameon = False)
axs[1,0].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[1,0].set_xticks([])
axs[1,0].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[1,0].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[2,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[1].soma_v, color='black', label='TC2 soma')
axs[2,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[1].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC2 dend')
axs[2,0].legend(frameon = False)
axs[2,0].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[2,0].set_xticks([])
axs[2,0].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[2,0].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[3,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[2].soma_v, color='black', label='TC3 soma')
axs[3,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[2].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC3 dend')
axs[3,0].legend(frameon = False)
axs[3,0].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[3,0].set_xticks([])
axs[3,0].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[3,0].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[4,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[3].soma_v, color='black', label='TC4 soma')
axs[4,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[3].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC4 dend')
axs[4,0].legend(frameon = False)
axs[4,0].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[4,0].set_xticks([])
axs[4,0].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[4,0].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[5,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[4].soma_v, color='black', label='TC5 soma')
axs[5,0].plot(t, ring.TCcells[4].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC5 dend')
axs[5,0].legend(frameon = False)
axs[5,0].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[5,0].set_xlabel('time (ms)')
axs[5,0].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[5,0].set_ylim([-100,50])
plt.show()

# RING 2 PLOTS
axs[0,1].plot(t, ring2.IN_1.soma_v, color='black', label='IN soma')
axs[0,1].plot(t, ring2.IN_1.dend_prox_v, color='grey', label='IN prox dend')
axs[0,1].plot(t, ring2.IN_1.dend_dist_v, color='red', label='IN dist dend')
axs[0,1].plot(t, ring2.IN_1.dend_dist2_v, color='blue', label='IN dist2 dend')
axs[0,1].legend(loc='upper right', frameon = False)
axs[0,1].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[0,1].set_xticks([]) # Use ax2's tick labels
axs[0,1].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[0,1].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[1,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[0].soma_v, color='black', label='TC1 soma')
axs[1,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[0].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC1 dend')
axs[1,1].legend(frameon = False)
axs[1,1].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[1,1].set_xticks([])
axs[1,1].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[1,1].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[2,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[1].soma_v, color='black', label='TC2 soma')
axs[2,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[1].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC2 dend')
axs[2,1].legend(frameon = False)
axs[2,1].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[2,1].set_xticks([])
axs[2,1].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[2,1].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[3,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[2].soma_v, color='black', label='TC3 soma')
axs[3,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[2].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC3 dend')
axs[3,1].legend(frameon = False)
axs[3,1].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[3,1].set_xticks([])
axs[3,1].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[3,1].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[4,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[3].soma_v, color='black', label='TC4 soma')
axs[4,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[3].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC4 dend')
axs[4,1].legend(frameon = False)
axs[4,1].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[4,1].set_xticks([])
axs[4,1].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[4,1].set_ylim([-100,50])

axs[5,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[4].soma_v, color='black', label='TC5 soma')
axs[5,1].plot(t, ring2.TCcells[4].dend_prox_v, color= 'grey', label='TC5 dend')
axs[5,1].legend(frameon = False)
axs[5,1].set_ylabel('mV')
axs[5,1].set_xlabel('time (ms)')
axs[5,1].set_xlim([50,300])
axs[5,1].set_ylim([-100,50])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `plt.show()`  twice. Remove the first `plt.show()` and just use it **once** after you have plotted all the figures.

```
axs[5,0].set_ylim([-100,50])
plt.show()    # <------------------ Remove this one

# RING 2 PLOTS
axs[0,1].plot(t, ring2.IN_1.soma_v, color='black', label='IN soma')
.
.
.
axs[5,1].set_ylim([-100,50])
plt.show()    # <------------------ Use only this one
```

Try also replacing

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
```

by

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 2, figsize=(20,20))
```

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot. but now i'm wondering why my figure is very small. Screen shot in my question post. Even when the second column is showing up now, the figure remains small regardless of what I put in fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))